# How do I add 2 links in condition? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I would like to add 2 links redirection for 2 different language pages:
like when i complete the email and the input should redirect to /signup or /inscription.

```
handleSubmit = () => {
const { lang, email } = this.state
const { search } = this.props
const { lang } = this.state

if (isEmailValid(email)) {
  if (search) {
    window.location =
      'https://example.com/inscription' + search + '&email=' + email
  } else {
    window.location = 'https://example.com/inscription?email=' + email
  }
} else {
  this.setState({
    error: lang.startBanner.error,
  })
}
```

}

Actually it only redirect to /inscription on FR page and EN page.
I tried this:

```
if (search) {
    window.location =
    this.state.lang === 'fr' ? 'https://example.com/inscription' : 'https://example.com/signup' + search + '&email=' + email
      // 'https://example.com/inscription' + search + '&email=' + email

  } else {
    // window.location = 'https://example.com/inscription?email=' + email
    window.location = this.state.lang === 'fr' ? 'https://example.com/inscription' : 'https://example.com/signup' + email
  }
```

````
    lang: fr,
    search: '',
    email: '',
    error: '',
    windowWidth: undefined,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window) {
      this.handleResize()
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
      this.setState({
        lang: window.location.pathname.includes('/fr') ? fr : en,
        search: window.location.search ? window.location.search : '',
      })
    }
  }```
````

Comment: hmmmm why this.state.fr? isn't it suppose to be like this.state.lang === 'fr' or something? can you go a little bit more indepth

Comment: Instead of window.location if its the same domain can't use react router

Comment: yeah it's not same domain, so it should looks like: this.state.lang === 'fr' ? 'https://example.com/inscription' : 'https://example.com/signup'}

Comment: What does this question even mean? You can't set `window.location` to 2 different locations.

Comment: @TKoL I have edited post, i don't get why i could not set window.location as it works for the link set in condition, i just want to make it for 2 links then when i'm on english page it redirects to /signup and not on /inscription. Sorry if i can't explain correctly i'm doing my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
window.location = this.state.lang === 'fr' ? 'https://example.com/inscription' : 'https://example.com/signup'
```

HandleSubmit :

```
  handleSubmit() {
    const { lang, email, search } = this.state;
    const url = this.state.url + (this.state.lang === "fr" ? "inscription" : "signup")
    if (this.isEmailValid(email)) {
      if (search) {
        window.location = url + search + "&email=" + email;
      } else {
        window.location = `${url}?email=` + email;
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        error: lang.startBanner.error
      });
    }
  }
```

I've also updated the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-boyd-evyef)

Comment: check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-lake-8nix9)

Comment: i checked and wrote the right code but redirects to /signup on FR and EN, i still don't get why it doesn't work, could you check what i tried in the condition above? please

Comment: @Julianis can you maybe make an example yourself? make it exactly as your local code, so I can fix whatever that you're doing wrong, because your code seems like it should work. try codesandbox or jsfiddle

Comment: could you check the bloc "handleSubmit" with the condition if and else, i want to know where should i put the code that you provided? should i delete the condition? i'm lost because the condition needs to check if the email is valid...

Comment: mine isn't s a select but input, like you put your email and send to external link and that autofills, could you show me an example with input please?

Comment: @Julianis it's exactly the same, just using an input, I've updated the answer